# Adjective that means two years/grades

Tags: single-word-requests

A two-year program is one that lasts for two years. Say, Sally’s in year 1 and she’s starting the program. In year 2, she will end the program. That’s not what I’m looking for.

I want an adjective to describe a program that will be offered to Sally, who’s in year 1, and at the same time, to Jack, who’s currently in year 2. It’s a program that will happen only once.

I’m doing some world-building and designing an academic program that’s offered to two years/grades concurrently. How would I describe such a program?

> A ________ program.

Comment: How long is the program? Do Sally and Jack continue into a second year of the program in Years 2 and 3 respectively?

Comment: @lightweaver Perhaps the adjective modifies the *offer* rather than the *program*. It would translate to something like "the program is offered to people in both years".

Comment: @AndrewLeach It lasts for a few weeks.

Comment: @Lawrence That would be a clear way of putting it. However, I’m still interested in a word that could be used in the form “A _____ program” if possible.

Comment: Possibly a *two-entry-year program*, but that wording it cumbersome.

Comment: Since you are doing worldbuilding, is there any word that describes your first two years? If they are maybe novices in the first two years, you could say a novice-level program.

Comment: If it's a program that's a few weeks in duration, offered to students in levels/grades 1 and 2, how about an "all-level program" to be clear that all students are welcome no matter their level, or else "multi-level/grade program". I'm having trouble finding a more precise single word without a clearer picture of the program/its context.

Comment: Building off of Helmar's comment, there are terms in U.S. High Schools (and possibly elsewhere) underclassmen and upperclassmen, which refer to "everyone except seniors" and "everyone except freshmen" respectively.  These each refer to a three-year span and overlap with the sophomores and juniors.  Perhaps for your story, you could invent a similar-sounding term.  There once was an author who got away with OWL-level and NEWT-level not so long ago.

Answer (score 1):

The term you want is ["multigrade"](https://www.reference.com/education/multigrade-classroom-2e6739cbc022e02e):

> A multigrade classroom is a single classroom that hosts a class made up of students in multiple grades. The students can be of different ages or of the same ages but in different grade levels.

Multigrade only makes sense for K-12 classes. In college, all classes are like that.

---

Alternatively, consider the term ["multiage"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-age_classroom):

> Multi-age classrooms or composite classes are classrooms with students from more than one grade level.

Comment: “In college, all classes are like that” — Not necessarily. Lots of classes in med school, for instance, are only offered to students in specific terms, at least here.